# What file formats are supported by Watson Speech to Text in Bluemix

Tags: audio, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

In the Watson SpeechToText in Bluemix the sample audio files are wav. Are there other file formats that are also supported? MP3 for example

Best Regards

W

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both audio/flac and audio/l16 MIME types are supported. If you use the audio/l16 MIME type, specify the rate and channels. For example, "audio/l16; rate=48000; channels=2". Ensure that the rate matches the rate at which the audio is captured.

Streaming is required for audio longer than 4MB. Streaming limit is 1 GB.

See the [API reference](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/#!/speech-to-text) and [Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/) for more detail :)

Comment: Thnx for the input Ed. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question don't forget to flag it as answered.

Comment: New here how do you flag it as answered? I didn't get this option using the flag link

Comment: There should be a (grey?) tick next to the voting on my answer. If you click that it goes green and flags the question as answered :)

Comment: pardon my ignorance, @EdShee is mp3 an audio/l16 MIME audio type?

Comment: @Joe.Zeppy Nope - the above are raw audio formats whereas an mp3 is a compressed audio file. Your audio needs to be decoded first before being sent as a stream to the API.

The API supports being sent a link to an audio file - it's possible that it'll accept mp3 there but you'd have to check the documentation to find out.